# How can i sort the directories as they appear on my hard disk?

Tags: c#

On my hard disk i have for example:

dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4
.....

My code is :

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(AutomaticsubDirectoryName);
DirectoryInfo[] subdirs = dInfo.GetDirectories();
```

so in `subdirs` i'm getting all the directories but they are not in the same order as they are on my hard disk.
How can i sort them so they will be in `subdirs` in the same order they are on my hard disk ?

---

Solved it by this:

```
DirectoryInfo[] subdirs = dInfo.GetDirectories().OrderBy(d =>
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        if (d.Name.Contains("Lightning ") && d.Name.Contains(" Length") && d.Name.IndexOf("Lightning ") < d.Name.IndexOf(" Length"))
                        {
                            string z = d.Name.Substring(("Lightning ").Length);
                            string f = z.Substring(0, z.IndexOf(" Length"));
                            if (Int32.TryParse(f, out i))
                                return i;
                            else
                                return -1;
                        }
                        else
                            return -1;
                    }).ToArray();
```

Working perfect.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need this for?

Comment: Do you know how they are in your hard disk?

Comment: Can you will be more specific?

Comment: How do you know the order of directories on your disc? Directories are not in an order on your hard disc. The application (windows explorer which I assume gives you an order) sorts this array before displaying it. So do the same sort it.

Comment: The directories in the file system can also have a specific order that can be changed from the user. Do you want to get the same order?

Comment: The reason is that i want to check for files in the first directory on the hard disk if there are files inside i want to show the first file from the first directory in a pictureBox. That;s why i want it to be the first directory and not another one.

Comment: Rafal for example the first directory from the top is: Lightning 0 Length 2 [91 - 93] second directory is: Lightning 1 Length 1 [96 - 97] so when im running the program in the constructor i want to get the information from the first directort Lightning 0 but instead in subdirs the first directory is Lightning 0 then Lightning 1 but then it's Lightning 10 11 12 13 14 then Lightning 2...So it's not in the same order it is on my hard disk.

Comment: That's not the order on your hard disk but how it's displayed to you. The order physically on hard disk is very low level and you shouldn't care about it. What you really want is to sort strings in natural order, which you shouldn't have trouble searching for.

Comment: Esailija ok but when i make later a loop over the subdirs it will loop the order in the subdirs Lightning 0 Lightning 1 Lightning 10...While i want it to loop it Lightning 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9...

Comment: Yes because it's sorted using code point values, whereas you want natural sort order...

Comment: Can you post your Solution as answer to your question? The answer isn´t a part of the question?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved it by this:

```
DirectoryInfo[] subdirs = dInfo.GetDirectories().OrderBy(d =>
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        if (d.Name.Contains("Lightning ") && d.Name.Contains(" Length") && d.Name.IndexOf("Lightning ") < d.Name.IndexOf(" Length"))
                        {
                            string z = d.Name.Substring(("Lightning ").Length);
                            string f = z.Substring(0, z.IndexOf(" Length"));
                            if (Int32.TryParse(f, out i))
                                return i;
                            else
                                return -1;
                        }
                        else
                            return -1;
                    }).ToArray();
```

Working perfect.

Answer (score 2):

The string compare function that Windows uses is exposed for everybody to use.  So you'll need a wee bit of pinvoke to get the exact same sort order as Explorer uses.  Wrapping it in an IComparer<> so you can just pass it to Array.Sort() or an OrderBy() Linq clause:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class LogicalComparer : IComparer<string> {
    public int Compare(string x, string y) {
        return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
    }
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string s1, string s2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about filesystems and how a software like Windows Explorer displays the names, I suppose you are talking about natural sorting the names. Read here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html

Answer (score 1):

`Craetion time` is the reasonable criteria how they are appears on the hard disk.

```
DirectoryInfo[] subdirs = dInfo.GetDirectories().OrderBy(d => d.CreationTime).ToArray();
```

Comment: I would suggest using d.FullName since by default they are usually sorted on the name.

Comment: Hamlet Hakobyan no it's not good yet still some directories not in place. While on my hard disk all directories are created on: 1/6/2013 10:26 AM

Comment: rydavilli no d.FullName give same results

Comment: Found a solution. Updated my question with the solution.