# Sorting a FileInfo[] based using Natural Sorting on the filename (SQL files)

Tags: c#, sorting

Here is my issue:

I am trying to run a bunch of SQL files that are using a naming system that looks like this:

1-createtable.sql

2-modifytable.sql

.....

10-createanothertable.sql

and so on.

The problem is, the code that I am using to get the files orders them using the filename as a string which results in the files being ordered like:

10-createanothertable.sql

1-createtable.sql

2-modifytable.sql

I need them ran by the numeric value before the "-".

I have read up and know this is called natural sorting but would like some sort of direction on the way to go.

Comment: Show your code. BTW: The answer to this (very common) problem is almost always to change your naming convention to pad the digits (for example 01 instead of 1.

Comment: Is it easy for you to change the naming system on the scripts or is that not an option? i.e. `000001-scriptname.sql,000002-scriptname.sql, to 999999-scriptname.sql`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716831/sorting-liststring-in-c-sharp http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting

Comment: You can use the LogicalComparer in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14295034/17034) to sort in "natural" sorting order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The quick way:**

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> fileInfosOrdered = fileInfos.OrderBy(fileInfo => int.Parse(fileInfo.Name.Substring(0, fileInfo.Name.IndexOf('-'))));
```

**The slow but thorough way(s):**

Read the links in the comment by Sam Leach.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a simpler approach by parsing the numeric values out of the filename and then storing them in a `System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` where the numeric value is the key and the file name is the value. Then when you iterate through the key value pairs the filenames will be in sorted order.

A simple parse to get the number value out would be something like:

```
string parts[] = filename.Split(new Char[] { '-'});
int numeric_part = UInt32.Parse(parts[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement like this :

```
var result = files.OrderByDesending(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.FullName, "^[0-9]+.+"));
```