# Sorting List<FileInfo> in Natural sorted order .

Tags: c#, list, fileinfo

I have a List which is being returned from a WCF service ,for List of files on Server.
Which i am later using to populate the TreeView in my Client Application

I need the list to be in naturally sorted order.

> For ex : 
>   I have a list something like `List-1` , and my expected result is `List-2` 
>   but i get `List-3` as my output.(refer list given below)

```
List-1          List-2          List-3
abc.jpg         abc.jpg         abc.jpg
abc10.jpg       abc10.jpg       abc10.jpg
abc100.jpg      abc97.jpg       abc100.jpg
abc98.jpg       abc98.jpg       abc101.jpg
abc97.jpg       abc100.jpg      abc102.jpg
abc102.jpg      abc101.jpg      abc97.jpg
abc101.jpg      abc102.jpg      abc98.jpg
```

So far i have looked into the stackoverflow's post  :

[1] :[C# Sort files by natural number ordering in the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077182/c-sharp-sort-files-by-natural-number-ordering-in-the-name)  [2]: [Sorting a FileInfo[] based using Natural Sorting on the filename (SQL files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803572/sorting-a-fileinfo-based-using-natural-sorting-on-the-filename-sql-files) .

None of them found to working for my case , Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Are your file names always contains non-numeric chars and then optional numbers?

Comment: How about [Natural Sort Order in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp) or [Natural Sorting in C#](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting)?

Comment: No it could be anything .. How we give file names in any file system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go; a handy list extension for natural sorting:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Demo
{
    // A List extension class for natural sorting.

    public static class ListExt
    {
        [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string lhs, string rhs);

        // Version for lists of any type.
        public static void SortNatural<T>(this List<T> self, Func<T, string> stringSelector)
        {
            self.Sort((lhs, rhs) => StrCmpLogicalW(stringSelector(lhs), stringSelector(rhs)));
        }

        // Simpler version for List<string>
        public static void SortNatural(this List<string> self)
        {
            self.Sort(StrCmpLogicalW);
        }
    }

    // Demonstrate using the List extension.

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var names = new List<FileInfo>
            {
                new FileInfo("abc.jpg"),
                new FileInfo("abc10.jpg"),
                new FileInfo("abc100.jpg"),
                new FileInfo("abc98.jpg"),
                new FileInfo("abc97.jpg"),
                new FileInfo("abc102.jpg"),
                new FileInfo("abc101.jpg")
            };

            names.SortNatural(x => x.Name);

            foreach (var name in names)
                Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }
}
```

The output from this program is:

```
abc.jpg
abc10.jpg
abc97.jpg
abc98.jpg
abc100.jpg
abc101.jpg
abc102.jpg
```

This takes advantage of the Windows API [`StrCmpLogicalW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method which does a natural sort order comparison, and uses P/Invoke to call it.

Comment: Sorry Watson but i don't want to do this , as it's already big application , adding Dll for a simple task won't be good enough, Their should be some easier ways too.

Comment: @MakIndia You are not adding a DLL; that DLL is already part of the Windows API and will already be installed on all versions of Windows. I seriously doubt you will find any easier way than this (which is effectively only using one line of code to declare the P/Invoke and one line to call it...)

Comment: Just clarifying my doubts :  Will it be always there i mean in all version of windows 7,8  , And what about its  access  permissions, What if a system is having limited access , still will it work fine .

Comment: @MakIndia Yes, it will work fine. It's a fundamental part of the Windows API which has been there since Windows 98. It is very VERY unlikely to be removed from any future version of Windows; that would break a LOT of applications!

Comment: Thanks a Lot  @Matthew Watson It worked  as expected .    +1 for providing such a nice example.

Comment: Hi Matthew , Can you please tell me How to use this same NaturalSort  For sorting a dictionary based on its key . I am not able to call it properly

Comment: @csharpcoder You would have to use `SortedDictionary` for this, along with a custom `IComparer<string>` implemented using `StrCmpLogicalW()`. This is not completely trivial, and it's a different question so you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: Thanks for reply Matthew , I got the solution, I am proceeding with that , Surely i will to frame it in a question and post here to.