# Weird order of directories enumerated

Tags: c#, directory, enumerate

I'm trying to write a small program which will give me the first folder name alphabetically. To test it, I gave it a folder which have these sub-folders:

> Season 4
>   Season 5
>   Season 6
>   Season 7
>   Season 8
>   Season 9
>   Season 10
>   Season 11

And this is the order I want my program to return. But when I run the following code:

```
string x = "";
foreach (string dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root))
{
      x += dir + Environment.NewLine;
}
MessageBox.Show(x);
```

The output is the following:

> Season 10
>   Season 11
>   Season 4
>   Season 5
>   Season 6
>   Season 7
>   Season 8
>   Season 9

How can I make my program start from 4 and go up to 11? 
Thanks in advance, Iliya

Comment: You need get and then sort the directory names using a natural sort order. See my recent answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/31538443/106159

Answer (score 1):

Your return data IS sorted!
1 is before 4, so the algorithm has performed correctly.  If you want to get the desired results without larger customization, you should rename your folders 'season 04' and so on.