# Sorting List<TextBox> Numerically C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have these `TextBoxes` labeled as `tb_class#` and `# = 1-10`

So far this is the function I have

```
    private List<TextBox> GetCustomClasses()
    {
        List<TextBox> tb = new List<TextBox>();
        foreach (Control con in gb_customClasses.Controls)
            if (con.Name.Contains("tb_class"))
                tb.Add(con as TextBox);
        return tb.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name.Replace("tb_class", "")).ToList();
    }
```

The output looks like this:

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
10
1
```

I could add a check for this, but I want it to go in perfect order. For those wondering `gb_customClasses` is a `groupbox`.

Solved! Final code:

```
    private List<TextBox> GetCustomClasses()
    {
        List<TextBox> tb = new List<TextBox>();
        foreach (Control con in gb_customClasses.Controls)
            if (con.Name.Contains("tb_class"))
                tb.Add(con as TextBox);
        return tb.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Name.Replace("tb_class", ""))).ToList();
    }
```

I didn't even think about adding `int.Parse`

Comment: Please show the data before replacing. Apparently you have sorted lexicographically on strings, not on a numerical type.

Comment: It's simple enough - you're processing the names of the controls, which are strings. If you're ordering alphabetically, they are in order! You need to compare them as a numeric type to get it to go in the order you want.

Comment: You can use Natural Sort Order for this kind of thing - [have a look at my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31538443/106159) and [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/248613/106159).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make a numerical sorting, rather than lexicographic. Try this:

```
return tb.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Name.Replace("tb_class", ""))).ToList();
```

Note, you might not have to call `.ToList()`, depending on your case. Returning an `IEnumerable<TextBox>` instead might be useful - so do check that out.

---

Don't be scared to use the `Tag` property to store some extra information on your controls! This solution is somewhat nicer:

```
return tb.OrderByDescending(x => (int)x.Tag);
```

or

```
return tb.OrderByDescending(x => ((MyClass)x.Tag).Index);
```

You just have to make sure you add an appropriate `Tag` for any `TextBox` you add to `gb_customClasses.Controls`. I would tend towards this approach if the controls are dynamically created (then tagging is easy, and naming not even a must)

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert it to an `int`, here's a LINQ only approach:

```
private List<TextBox> GetCustomClasses()
{
    return gb_customClasses.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
        .Where(txt => txt.Name.StartsWith("tb_class"))
        .OrderByDescending(txt => int.Parse(txt.Name.Substring("tb_class".Length)))
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting them alphabetically, change your return statement to:

```
return tb.OrderByDescending(x => Int32.Parse(x.Name.Replace("tb_class", ""))).ToList();
```

In order to get the list sorted numerically

Answer (score 0):

You should be comparing them as numbers, and not strings:

```
return tb.OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Name.Replace("tb_class", ""))).ToList();
```

Adding that little bit converts the name where you removed the `tb_class` from a string to an int.

Answer (score 0):

modify to

OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Name.Replace("tb_class", "")))

Answer (score 0):

> I have these TextBoxes labeled as "tb_class#" and # = 1-10

With such encoding, you can utilize the fact that numbers with more digits are bigger, and also LINQ sort is **stable**. In other words, simply order first by the text length, then by the text:

```
return tb.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name.Length).ThenByDescending(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

This might work:

```
private List<TextBox> GetCustomClasses()
{
    List<TextBox> tb = new List<TextBox>();

    List<String> indexes = new List<string>();

    //  N.B. A more conservative implementation might want to go for an unsigned 
    //  64-bit thing here. Just in case you run into a really big GroupBox.
    //  
    //  **WARNING** Due to Brexit, UK compilers will be changing to base 12, which 
    //  may adversely affect the performance of this loop. Also keep an eye out for 
    //  unpredictable fluctuations in the exchange rate with UK integers. 

    for (String i = "0"; Int32.Parse(i) < 0x7fffffff; i = (Int32.Parse(i) + 1).ToString())
    {
        indexes = indexes.Union(new string[] { i }).ToList();
    }

    var arrayOfIndexes = indexes.ToArray();

    //  Leave room for null terminator
    var reordered = new TextBox[gb_customClasses.Controls.Count + 1];

    foreach (Control con in gb_customClasses.Controls)
        if (con.Name.Contains("tb_class"))
            reordered[arrayOfIndexes.ToList().IndexOf(con.Name.Replace("tb_class", ""))] = con as TextBox;

    return reordered.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Notoriously unneeded complextion

Comment: @SimpleVar Should I have made `indexes` unsigned?

Comment: Not sure if troll..? At the very least you should know that `List<T>` has an `Add` method, rather than `.Union().ToList()`

Comment: And why on earth loop over *strings* up to `0x7fffffff`? I mean, I guess it could pass as a troll post

Comment: "Also keep an eye out for unpredictable fluctuations in the exchange rate with UK integers." -- *What is going on*