# Sort Fileinfo list in asc order

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I have a list of files as follows

```
10_2017
123_2018
500_2017
20_2019
100_2017
25_2017
32_2018
```

Which i want to be sorted like

```
10_2017
25_2017
100_2017
500_2017
32_2018
123_2018
20_2019
```

I can sort the array by `Array.sort(f1,new FileInfoSort)` if I read the years separate but I need it in one sorted array or list

I have tried several threads on here including this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31538443/2625656). used `f1.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name))` and `Array.Sort(f1.toArray, New FileInfoSort)` without any success
I have even tried to separate the files into folders by year and read them separately into lists and combining them which didnt seem to work either

Using the code

```vb
Dim d1 As New DirectoryInfo(AppFolder)
Dim f1 As List(Of FileInfo) = d1.GetFiles("*.LBK", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList
'f1.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name))
f1.SortNatural(Function(x) x.Name)
```

Separating the files into folders by year and then reading it and combining

```vb
        Dim d1 As New DirectoryInfo(AppFolder.User.data)
        Dim d2 As List(Of DirectoryInfo) = New List(Of DirectoryInfo)
        'data folders have names like "d_2019"
        For Each d As DirectoryInfo In d1.GetDirectories
            If d.Name.ToString.Substring(0, 1) = "d" Then d2.Add(d)
        Next
        Dim f1 As List(Of FileInfo) = New List(Of FileInfo)
        For Each Dir As DirectoryInfo In d2
            f1.AddRange(Dir.GetFiles("*.LBK", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            'trying to sort
            'f1.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name))
            f1.SortNatural(Function(x) x.Name)
        Next
```

```vb
Module ListExt
    <DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Private Function StrCmpLogicalW(ByVal lhs As String, ByVal rhs As String) As Integer

    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Sub SortNatural(Of T)(ByVal self As List(Of T), ByVal stringSelector As Func(Of T, String))
        self.Sort(Function(lhs, rhs) StrCmpLogicalW(stringSelector(lhs), stringSelector(rhs)))
    End Sub

    <Extension()>
    Sub SortNatural(ByVal self As List(Of String))
        self.Sort(AddressOf StrCmpLogicalW)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Any method Ive used so far outputs

```
10_2017
20_2019
25_2017
32_2018
100_2017
123_2018
500_2017
```

I have no idea how to approach this even. If such a list/array is not possible ideas of how i might structure my files so that i can read in the files in the order i prefer above would be welcome too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write code to parse the separate sections of the name and treat them as numbers. Any built-in comparer you use will treat strings as strings, where anything that starts with a 1 comes before anything that starts with a 2, even when the values are '100' and '2'. Even the so-called "natural" sorts are only good enough to check the first section.

You also need to strip the `LBK` extension from the name.

```
Dim splitChars() As Char = {"_"c}
Dim d1 As New DirectoryInfo(AppFolder)
Dim f1 As List(Of FileInfo) = 
   d1.EnumerateFiles("*.LBK", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
   OrderBy(Function(fi) 
              Dim parts = fi.Name.Replace(".LBK", "").Split(splitChars)
              Return (Integer.Parse(parts(1)) * 1000) + Integer.Parse(parts(0))
           End Function).
   ToList()
```

For fun, here's a Regex version:

```
Dim exp As New Regex("(\d{1,3})_(\d{4})");

Dim d1 As New DirectoryInfo(AppFolder)
Dim f1 As List(Of FileInfo) = 
   d1.EnumerateFiles("*.LBK", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
   OrderBy(Function(fi) 
              Dim parts = exp.Matches(fi.Name)(0).Groups
              Return (Integer.Parse(parts(2).Value) * 1000) + Integer.Parse(parts(1).Value)
           End Function).
   ToList()
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/UAae8P

---

I also wanted to comment on this line from one of the samples in the question:

```
If d.Name.ToString.Substring(0, 1) = "d" Then d2.Add(d)
```

It stood out as needing some attention. There's a *ton* of extra work going on here that isn't needed:

- d.Name is already a string, no need to call `ToString()`
- Since you just want one character you can access it via subscript, no need to call `Substring()`
- You're comparing *one character*, no need to do string compares.

You really want this:

```
If d.Name(0) = "d"c Then d2.Add(d)
```

That's a *lot* less code, and it will perform so much better, and it will be worth your time to study this and understand why.

Comment: I knew calling the `ToString` was unnecessary but i did not know you can `d.Name(0)`.